# Looking for PyQt4 embeddable terminal widget

Tags: python, pyqt

I wrote an application that, among other things, launches some "backend" processes to do some stuff.
These subprocesses are very likely to fail or have unexpected behavior since they have to operate in quite hard conditions, so I prefer to give full control over them to the operator.

**NOTE:** I am running these processes using a `subprocess` module based class instead of `QProcess` to have some more control functionality over the running process.

At the moment, I'm using a `QPlainTextEdit` widget to which I append standard output/error from the subprocess, plus some buttons to quickly send some common signals (INT, STOP, CONT, KILL, ..), but:

- In some cases it would be useful to send some input too. Although it could be done with a text input box, I would prefer using something more "professional"
- Of course, there is no direct way to interpret special control characters, such as color codes, cursor movement, etc..
- I had to implement an auto-scroll management of the console, but it is not guaranteed 100% to work nicely (sometimes the scroll locking doesn't work as expected, etc.)

So: does anyone know something I could use to accomplish these needs?

I found [qtermwidget](http://qtermwidget.sourceforge.net/) but it seems more oriented on handling a shell process (and the Python bindings seems to let you run `/bin/bash` only) by itself than communicating with an already existing process I/O.

Comment: @gruszczy: why did you retag from `pyqt4` to `pyqt`? They are two very different Python modules, since `pyqt` was the bindings for the old Qt3 while, of course, PyQt4 is the one for Qt4..

Answer (score 4):

Does something like this help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import  sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class embterminal(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.terminal = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)
        self.process.start(
                'xterm',['-into', str(self.terminal.winId())])
        # Works also with urxvt:
        #self.process.start(
                #'urxvt',['-embed', str(self.terminal.winId())])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embterminal()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it was possible doing that.. it still needs some tweaking (eg. the row count inside the terminal is wrong) but in general seems to be working fine..

Comment: Perhaps you know something about the communicating part and you can help me out with a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14772138/406686

Comment: is it possible to read environment variables to the python application to display info instead of everytime having to type echo command ?

Comment: The problem with xterm is look and feel. The Xterm look and feel is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could try QConsole (http://qconsole.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used it, but it looks like the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: I just tried it, but it seems not to be as cool as the description promises.. I was only able to compile the stand-alone example, and did not find any instruction on how to build a Python module. Also, the example itself seems to be quite buggy, at least when compiled against Qt4 (that will use q3support, as specified on the project page..). I guess that the project focuses more on the TCL imlementation than on the Python one..

Comment: That's a shame. I'm not aware of any others, unfortunately.